# How to install the Human icon theme?

Tags: icons

I want to install old ubuntu 6.06LTS Dapper Drake icon set in my ubuntu 12.04LTS Precise Pangolin.
Where can i get the ICON theme of ubuntu 6.06 for ubuntu 12.04. even if i download from any site how can i install it in my latest 12.04 ?

please anybody knows how to install old iconset of ubuntu 6.06 in latest version

HOW CAN I INSTALL HUMAN-CLEARLOOK orange theme of UBUNTU 6.06LTS  in 12.04?

I install the human-theme from synaptic but GTK goes wrong and theme wont get apply..I think it need particular GTK-Engine. Anyone knows how can i get human orange theme in 12.04

I get theme like this

[image]

I want theme alike that we had during 6.06LTS

Comment: Will the Apple II icon set do instead?

Comment: I like the pretty old UBUNTU 6.06LTS human theme (orange). I tired to install theme in 12.04lts but its gtk goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Human icon set can be found in Synaptic Package Manager or Software Centre.

Just open up the synaptic package manager and type human over there.

In software center click to show technical items at bottom.

Mark `human-icon-theme` for installation and apply the setting for installation.

When done, open up the MyUnity app and tweak over there to change the icon theme to human.

Comment: I think using the Software Center is easier and more user friendly than the Synaptic Package Manager

Comment: I did search it in software center, but no use many config files can be found only in synaptic package manager and not in software center. see the difference when u type particular word in both

Comment: I did find it the software center, try typing the whole thing (`human-icon-theme`), when there is a lot of results try clicking on the "show technical items" at the bottom

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to click Technical result.. you are right @Dan